# Rotational Barriers - Amide and Hydroxamic Acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, resonance, carbonyl-compounds

Why the barrier to rotation about the $\ce{C-N}$ bond higher in an amide than it is in a hydroxamic acid? (MO-based explanation preferred)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can check out molecular orbitals of *N*-methylacetamide here](http://wchem.cup.lmu.de/worbit/methylacetamide.html). Unticking the *spin*-box will stop the molecule spinning. The important orbitals are $\ce{HOMO} -1$ and $\ce{HOMO} - 2$. (The actual HOMO is not part of the $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-system.)

The same site also features a low-level [Simple Hückel Molecular Orbit Calculator](http://wchem.cup.lmu.de/SHMO/index.html). I used that to create the four images below of the $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-system of *N*-hydroxyformamide. From left to right the atoms are $\ce{O-N-C=O}$

[image: 1st pi orbital]

[image: 2nd pi orbital]

[image: 3rd pi orbital]

[image: 4th pi orbital]

The lowest $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-orbital is always bonding across the entire $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-system. In *N*-methylacetamide, the second $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-orbital has a nodal plain almost directly on the carbon, only slightly moved towards the carbonyl oxygen (theory tells me that, I can’t actually *see* that good in the model). The third $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-orbital is empty and thus does not participate in bonding. This means that each bond ($\ce{N-C}$ and $\ce{C=O}$ can be regarded as something between a single and a double bond — in accordance with the Lewis resonance structures. There is considerable overlap to be lost on rotating the system around $\ce{N-C}$.

In the hydroxamic acid, the second and third $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-orbitals (the occupied ones) only have very little electron density in the $\ce{N-C}$ bond. In fact, the lowest MO is largest for the $\ce{O-N}$ bond, the second is (weakly) antibonding concerning $\ce{O-N}$ and has the largest contributions on $\ce{C=O}$. The third is again antibonding along $\ce{O-N}$. Altogether this means that most of the electron density is between $\ce{O-N}$ and between $\ce{C=O}$ — the $\ce{N-C}$ bond only carries very little density and is thus much better described by a single bond. Much less resonance is lost when rotating, so the rotational barrier is lower.

Comment: I could insert somewhere that you can check ron’s structures for resonance but … w/e ;)

Comment: I will sound now really nitpicking, but I was looking more for a qualitative approach, without computations, as this is an exercise from Ian Fleming's Molecular Orbitals. Nevertheless, if no such answer appears I will accept this one.

Comment: *Qualitative* is rather hard imho, because the six-electron $\pi$-system is rather unknown. But maybe I can draw/write one up, too …

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is because the said bond has more "double" character in the former case. And that, in turn, is because the presence of electronegative substituent makes nitrogen less eager to share its lone pair, which otherwise could have contributed to the resonance structure with $\ce{N+=C-O-}$ fragment.